# How to keep hr line in same line for all devices?

Tags: html, css

I want to keep `img`, `p`, `span` & `hr` in the same line for all device. But for some devices `hr` is going to bottom. I have tried below way:

**[WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y0z4vcf5/)**

```css
.image-header img,
.image-header p,
.image-header span,
.image-header .hr-line {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.image-header .hr-line {
  border-top: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  width: 100%;
}

.image-header img {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: solid 1px #eeeeee;
  margin: -.8% 1% 0% 0%;
}

.image-header p {
  color: #000000;
  margin-right: 7px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.image-header span {
  margin-top: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #878787;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: solid 1px #dcdcdc;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="image-header">
        <img src="assets/images/red-dress.png" alt="">
        <p>Red swing dress.jpg</p>
        <span>8</span>
        <hr class="hr-line">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I use below code than it works for desktop but if I try for small device it go to bottom. How can I solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

```
.image-header .hr-line {
  width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: Are you using bootsrap ?

Comment: @XxSTREKxX yes..

Comment: `hr` is probably not the correct element to use here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you expecting like this:
use `display:flex` and `flex-grow:1`

```
.image-header {
  display: flex;
}

.image-header .hr-line {
  border-top: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```css
.image-header img,
.image-header p,
.image-header span,
.image-header .hr-line {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.image-header {
  display: flex;
}

.image-header .hr-line {
  border-top: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.image-header img {
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: -.8% 1% 0% 0%;
}

.image-header p {
  color: #000000;
  margin-right: 7px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.image-header span {
  margin-top: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #878787;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: solid 1px #dcdcdc;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="image-header">
        <img src="assets/images/red-dress.png" alt="">
        <p>Red swing dress.jpg</p>
        <span>8</span>
        <hr class="hr-line">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

added display:flex to `.image-header` and removed `border` and added `height` and `background` to `.hr-line`

```css
.image-header img,
.image-header p,
.image-header span,
.image-header .hr-line {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.image-header .hr-line {
  width: 100%;
  background: #dcdcdc;
  height: 1px;
}

.image-header img {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: solid 1px #eeeeee;
  margin: -.8% 1% 0% 0%;
}

.image-header p {
  color: #000000;
  margin-right: 7px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.image-header span {
  margin-top: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #878787;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: solid 1px #dcdcdc;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

.image-header {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="image-header">
        <img src="assets/images/red-dress.png" alt="">
        <p>Red swing dress.jpg</p>
        <span>8</span>
        <hr class="hr-line">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you use `col-md-12`. And you have to give `height` `width` to image.

Answer (score 0):

The reason hr goes to the bottom on a small device is that you set the width of hr using a percentage, and its width will depend on the width of the parent container. So on the small screen the width of hr will become smaller as the width of the parent container becomes smaller, and the width of img, p, span is absolute. So when their widths add up to the width of the parent container, it will cause a line break.
If you just want them to be on one line, you can do this in the following ways:

1. set `.image-header` nowrap

```css
.image-header {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

2. set `.img-header` display `flex`, and make `hr`'s width adaptive

```
.img-header {
  display: flex;
}

.image-header .hr-line{
  border-top: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

3. if you are sure the sum of (span, img, p)'s width and margin, you can use `calc`，suppose the sum of the width and their margin is `230px`

```
.image-header .hr-line{
  border-top: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  width: calc(100% - 230px);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can give to every element a width. I did it you can try it.

```css
.image-header img,
.image-header p,
.image-header span,
.image-header .hr-line {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.image-header .hr-line {
  border-top: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  width: 5%;
}

.image-header img {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: solid 1px #eeeeee;
  margin: -.8% 1% 0% 0%;
  width:30%;
}

.image-header p {
  color: #000000;
  margin-right: 7px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  width:30%;
}

.image-header span {
  margin-top: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #878787;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: solid 1px #dcdcdc;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  width:5%;
}
```